# Apache redirect everything under a folder except the folder itself

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

At some point in the past, our site had a structure like `www.example.com/departments/it` or `www.example.com/departments/asdf`. Then, the the paths changed to something like `www.example.com/it` or `www.example.com/asdf`, getting rid of the 'departments'.

There is content that now lives under the `/departments/` path, so using the following rewrite rule doesn't work

> RewriteRule ^/departments/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Because while it rewrites everything under departments, departments itself gets redirected back to the site root.

How do I prevent this so that if I go to `www.example.com/it` it works, `www.example.com/departments/it` redirects to `www.example.com/it`, and if I go to `www.example.com/departments/`, I get the department information?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in and give it a try

> RewriteRule ^/departments/it$  /it/$1 [R=301,R,L]